# Send special characters with email()

Tags: php, email, html-entities

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I have a contact form that send the message with this code:

```
$SUCCESS = mail(

    $EMAIL_TO,

    "Richiesta informazioni",

    "Questo messaggio e' stato inviato tramite la pagina 'Contatti' del sito ".$WEBSITE."; non rispondere a questo messaggio ma servirsi dei contatti lasciati dal mittente.\r\n\r\n".
    "Inviato da: ".$_POST['nome']."\r\n".
    "IP Address: ".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."\r\n".
    "Contatti: ".$_POST['contatti']."\r\n".
    "------------------------------------------------------\r\n".
    $_POST['messaggio']."\r\n",

    "Reply-To: ".$COMPANY." <".$EMAIL_TO.">\r\n".
    "Return-Path: ".$COMPANY." <".$EMAIL_TO.">\r\n".
    "From: ".$COMPANY." <".$WEBSITE.">\r\n".
    "Organization: ".$COMPANY."\r\n".
    "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n".
    "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n".
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit",

    "-f".$EMAIL_TO

);
```

The problem is that, if I send special characters...

```
¡
¢
£
¤
¥
```

...I receive translated characters:

```
&Acirc;&iexcl;
&Acirc;&cent;
&Acirc;&pound;
&Acirc;&curren;
&Acirc;&yen;
```

Of course I've tried lots of the solutions suggested in other discussions:

```
// it's just a list - not the code I used! I've tryed lots of combinations.
iconv_set_encoding("internal_encoding", "UTF-8");
iconv_set_encoding("output_encoding", "ISO-8859-1");
htmlspecialchars(...);
mb_convert_encoding(...);
```

I obteined a result just with **mb_convert_encoding**:

```
$message = mb_convert_encoding($message, 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');
```

But it isn't a definitive solution, because I if I use this function I obtain:

```
Â¡
Â¢
Â£
Â¤
Â¥
```

I'm sorry it this question is not useful for the community! Unfortunally I ran out of ideas and I need help...what I'm missing???

Comment: What is contained in `$_POST['messaggio']`? Are `&Acirc; -> Â` or any other not wanted special character already in it before you encode?

Comment: People need to know what exactly you have been trying, and the matching results, not a mix of everything. For a start, tell us what you are trying right now and what is the result right now.

Comment: @Fabio: How can I see that?

Comment: @Adder: Read the message, is very clear: if I try the first part of code I obtain "&Acirc;&iexcl;". If I use every combination of the functions suggested nothing change. If I transform the $message with mb_convert_encoding($message, 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES') I obtain "Â¡" (the character sent is '¡')

Comment: use `echo $_POST['messaggio'];`

Comment: @Fabio - I did. I see 'Â¡ Â¢ Â£ Â¤ Â¥'. If I try to look at the source the browser tell me that I need to send the form again. If I analize the character with chrome I see the same (Â¡ Â¢ Â£ Â¤ Â¥), but maybe here the characters are already rendered.

Comment: As you see `Â` are already in there, so it's not an encoding problem, `mb_convert_encoding` did the job quite good as far as you wrote. You should check for your form, there must be something that adds `Â` in your message textarea

Comment: SOLVED! I've prepared the test list in a txt file that uses ANSI. I converted it in UTF-8 and Â disappeared. Thank you very much for taking the time to help me!

Comment: @Marco You must have be doing something like `htmlspecialchars` to get the html entities &Acirc;&iexcl; etc. The `Â` are not a problem, it just means the input is already in UTF-8 format, and does not need to be converted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change header:

```
 "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n";
```

To

```
 "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n";
```

below code 
i have changed u can add n check

```
"Reply-To: ".$COMPANY." <".$EMAIL_TO.">\r\n".
"Return-Path: ".$COMPANY." <".$EMAIL_TO.">\r\n".
"From: ".$COMPANY." <".$WEBSITE.">\r\n".
"Organization: ".$COMPANY."\r\n".
"MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n".
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n".
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit",

"-f".$EMAIL_TO
```

i checked with below code and its working

```
<?php
mail(

    "check with ur email",

    "Richiesta informazioni",

    "Questo messaggio e' stato inviato tramite la pagina 'Contatti' del sito; non rispondere a questo messaggio ma servirsi dei contatti lasciati dal mittente.\r\n\r\n".
    "Inviato da: santanu\r\n".
    "IP Address: santanu\r\n".
    "Contatti: santanu\r\n".
    "------------------------------------------------------\r\n
    message ¡
¢
£
¤
¥\r\n",

    "Reply-To: test <your email>\r\n".
    "Return-Path: test<your email>\r\n".
    "From: test <your email>\r\n".
    "Organization: test\r\n".
    "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n".
    "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n".
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit",

    "-fyour email"

);

?>
```

Comment: As with mb_convert_encoding() I obtain: "Â¡ Â¢ Â£ Â¤ Â¥". Why before every character I get 'Â'?

Comment: bcaz u r sending the contents as plain text so all special characters get affected..

Comment: Â contains the escape code / prefix for the latin code plane in UTF-8.

Comment: I confirm, I obtain "Â¡ Â¢ Â£ Â¤ Â¥", even though I changed /plain to /html

Comment: I'm sending just a list of characters (one per line): ¡
¢
£
¤
¥

Comment: i added new code .also i checked the code in localhost its working can u check with that code also use ur email id there

Comment: You are right: If I enter the characters directly everything work correctly! What does it happend to $_POST['messaggio']? I don't apply any filter before using email().

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30498/discussion-between-santanu-kumar-and-marco-panichi)

Comment: SOLVED! See my last comment under the question. Thank you very much Santanu for the help.

Comment: u need to send the values as html pattern like &amp;&copy;&euro;&sum;&Psi; for &©€∑Ψ if u r using as post message..i checked and  its working...